# Can anyone explain me why this chain does not move?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

Even, if this chain does not move then what will happen if the chain will move?
can anyone elaborate "Epitaph of Stevinus" to me? I think it's applicable for all shapes of triangle until the chain is attached to the surface. In this case, we assume there is no friction and I want to know the answer of question in terms of energy not by the force method.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a gravitational field, things fall downward under the force of gravity. As they do so, they convert gravitational potential energy into kinetic energy. If we put the chain in place and it spontaneously starts to move, it must be converting something into kinetic energy, and the only other form of energy in the system is potential, so that must be the source. Since all the chain links are identical, when the chain has rotated by one link, we are in the exact same position we started with, in which the chain moved spontaneously.

We can see that if the chain moves to begin with, it constantly convert gravitational potential into kinetic energy, accelerating without bound. This of course makes no sense, there is not infinite potential energy stored in the chain to start with. The chain cannot "fall" forever without actually going anywhere, the resolution is simply that the chain doesn't move at all.

Comment: well why can't it as  3rd kind of perpetual machine which does not violate 1 and 2 law of themodyanmics and  just runs forever without taking extra  energy and giving it only doing their motion in frictionless world. then why can't   chain cannot "fall" forever without actually going anywhere

Comment: If i am wrong please correct me

Comment: @ayu Perpetual motion of the third kind is *uniform motion* - if you eliminate friction, the chain can indeed be set into motion by an external force and then just spin forever. The problem is, the chain starts at rest and then begins to accelerate - it's not uniform motion. The chain's kinetic energy increases from zero, but its potential energy never decreases, violating conservation of energy.  If gravity can accelerate the chain from rest, it will never stop, and will just keep accelerating it forever.

Comment: okk now I get it .but I will wait for some other answer also as what is was seeking it is not. It is a different approach to what i wanted to know

Comment: What approach do you want? you did not want forces, so you got explanations by energy conservation. So for what dio you wait, explain your doubts.